# ThreadPool vs Dedicated Thread for continuously running background task

Tags: multithreading, threadpool

I'm implementing a server with the main purpose of exposing an API. Some of the data for the requests is gathered by reading information from the system.

To not block the server from responding to API requests, these I/O tasks will be delegated to separate threads.

I plan on running these I/O tasks each second, meaning there will be at least 2 to 3 tasks each second. The execution should be rather quick - reading from the file system and doing some basic calculations with the values.

Now where the problem lies: I'm not really sure what the best design approach for this specific problem is. I could either use 2 or 3 dedicated threads for each task - executing the work, putting the thread to sleep until the next execution. Or I could use a `ThreadPool` and push each second 2 to 3 jobs into the worker queue.

What do you think is the idiomatic way to design such a system?

Comment: Whatever language or framework you use for your API probably uses a Threadpool already. Putting a thread to sleep, waking it up and rescheduling it are expensive operations. Frameworks use threadpools to avoid the rescheduling cost. Besides, 2-3 seconds is a *huge* time for modern processors. Using a threadpool you'll be able to server the same requests with far fewer threads

Comment: In most languages IO operations can be performed asynchronously too. IO is performed by file or network drivers, quite often using OS threads. Instead of having an application thread block waiting for the driver to complete, you could use an asynchronous operation that would release the application thread back to the threadpool until the IO operation finishes

Comment: The benefit of using async operation is that no additional thread is needed. This can make things significantly simpler since there is no need for lock/atomic/synchronizations nor issue related to parallelism (eg. race conditions) not to mention async operations can theoretically be faster than using N threads though some time it is better to use multiple thread (eg on SSDs).